# is it possible to detect a parents transformation in the child?

Tags: java, javafx-2

The javadoc of javafx.scene.Group says:

> Any transform, effect, or state applied to a Group will be applied to all children of that group

But is it possible tot detect a transform applied to a Group in its children? Ie is there a property on the child you can listen to if the parent Group gets a transformation applied to it? I tried listening to layoutXProperty(), translateXProperty(), getTransforms() but couldn't detect a change there.

Comment: Did you try to listen transformsProperty() of a parent?

Comment: I'm asking, because, as far as I remember that code, transforms are just applied to children, and children's properties are not modified about this.

Comment: The parent of course gets a transform to which I could listen to, but I was wandering if I could detect this change in the child, without having the use a reference to the parent.

Comment: I think, the answer is - no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add transformation to a node, this transformation will be propogated by internal scenegraph rendering mechanism on all its children (if applicable, and if there are no bugs), and there is no way to know in a children about it. Children's transformations lists correspond to the transformations, which should be applied to  that node, and its children and is set by user, and this list (or according properties) will not notify you about transformations, which are done from parents.